# Jerks in List view on scrolling up and down

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, baseadapter

I am working on a project in which i have to get data from web service and show into list view. Now problem is this that i am showing all data in list view nut jerks in list view.
 I searched a lot but no solution.removed notifyDataSetChanged() but no solution.
Need Help

Comment: sounds like you have some performance issues in your adapter.  It would help if you showed this code.

Comment: Show us your code. Are you experiencing lags in scorll ? Also show us the xml layout in which your listview is in

Comment: Also your adapter for listview.